# xmlstarlet to comma separated values

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have an XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>B2B_ProductDetailDesktop</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Class1</members>
        <members>Class2</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>54.0</version>
</Package>
```

I need to extract the members value to a comma separated list, only for the ApexCLass type.
In the given example, this should output this:

```
CLass1,Class2
```

I try with

```
xmlstarlet sel -N d=http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata -t -m "//d:Package/d:types" -v "d:members" temp/package/package.xml
```

But it outputs only

```
B2B_ProductDetailDesktopClass1
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (assuming a POSIX shell):

```sh
xmlstarlet select -T -t \
  -m "/_:Package/_:types[_:name='ApexClass']/_:members" \
    -i "position() != 1" -o "," -b  \
    -v "." \
  -b -n \
file.xml
```

By default (`--doc-namespace` being in effect) namespaces declared in
the input document can be referred to without explicit `-N` options;
the default namespace is bound to the `_` / `DEFAULT` prefix.
See the user's guide
[ch. 5](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html#idm47989546158480).